# Is there any book about inequality?

Tags: reference-request, inequality

I heard there is a book name 'inequality'.

But I couldn't find the book.

Is there any site or book about inequalities?

What i want is collection of inequalities.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the Cauchy Schwarz Masterclass is a book about inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521358809) by googling on "inequalities math book."  The search also led to two other, recent books in a blog posting by [John Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/06/03/three-books-on-inequalities/).

Answer (score 2):

You might be talking about [Inequalities](http://www.amazon.in/Inequalities-Little-Mathematics-Library-Korovkin/dp/0828532214) by P. P. Korovkin.

Answer (score 2):

I am not into inequalities. But many people who know that stuff have mentioned the book by Hardy, Littlewood and Polya as a classic: [http://www.amazon.com/Inequalities-Cambridge-Mathematical-Library-Hardy/dp/0521358809](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521358809)